# Documentation for express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Like Java there is http://www.docjar.com/ to view source code of all classes in java ,is there any resource to view source code of express module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the SOURCE code, not the API documentation, Github is usually your friend these days:

https://github.com/expressjs/express

It's not as friendly as DocJar though.

Answer (score 0):

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html ?

i'm asking, now if that's the answer, hurray ?